# Ubuntu Server - Games?

Tags: server, games

I have a small Ubuntu Server at home and i wanted to try to play a graphical game on it. Are there any games that can be started in command line and are played normal with keyboard (and maybe mouse)? I dont mean text-only games. I mean games like shooters.

Comment: Take a look at the Software Centre, what have you tried so far, how much RAM do you have, how much Disk space do you have and how fast is the processor? This information needs to be added to your question as, in its present state it does not appear to have involved a lot of research.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do in Ubuntu Desktop can be done in Ubuntu Server and vice versa. The big difference is that Ubuntu Server doesn't come with a desktop by default. But you can easily install one if you want, like `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: For a system that's actually being used as a production server (which, admittedly, it seems this might not be), it's [generally discouraged](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI#Arguments_Against_a_GUI) to install a GUI for security and stability reasons. (This is still a good answer; it's just that this should be mentioned.)

Comment: I dont want to install a gui! I just want to start the game in console and then play it in fullscreen.